# Docker Swarm monitoring solution for two swarm clusters in different VLANs

Tags: docker, monitoring, docker-swarm, swarm

We have two docker swarm clusters in production in different virtual local area networks (for example LAN and DMZ) on own server infrastructures (not cloud).
And we need to monitor them (swarm's machines and services) from one dedicated monitoring solution to consolidate all metrics in one dash board (yeah, we need dash board,  out of the box)
It need to be fault tolerance and need to be isolated from both swarms, of course.
Because one of networks is DMZ, we can't do any outgoing connection from DMZ to LAN for monitoring-agents (agents on DMZ's Swarm cluster) - it seems, we need outgoing connection from main monitoring service to agents.

Could u help us to find best and maybe most popular monitoring solutions for Docker Swarm that fits to described requirenments?

Answer (score 0):

Try Portainer. It has two types of agents: one (edge) needs to connect to server instance (which you don't want) but the other doesn't, see https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/agent.html

Portainer agents need to have access to docker socket on machines so when installed on swarm managers, you can manage as many swarms need.

It's free and opensource so if you need something that's missing, you can always build a custom fork :)